# Negative numbers of type unsigned char

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, correlation

I am implementing 2D correlation code from scratch and I have a simple 3x3 image matrix of type unsigned char:

```
 unsigned char Image = [184   0   35
                        48   107  193
                        29   166  32]
```

My correlation kernel

```
             Kernel = [-1 0 1]
```

Now, when I perform correlation, the result from first row is -149 mathematically, but the printed result is 107 (2's complement).

```
unsigned char res = -1.F *(Kernel[i-1]) + (Kernel[i+1]);
```

Isn't that a mistake? How can I save the result as -149 but the type still remains as unsigned char?
I know my question might not be appropriate as the range of unsigned char is 0 to 255, but I wanted to make sure if I am missing something. I am also aware about negative numbers being converted to 2's complement.
BTW, this is not any homework, I am just working on C/C++ from image processing perspective.

Comment: -149 cannot be represented in a `char`. `char` is limited to the range -128..+127. Use `int` instead of `unsigned char`.

Comment: 184 is int(signed), -1 is int, multiplication is int, then converted and downgraded to uchar as 107

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you need a negative value then obviously you can't store it in an unsigned type. Use a signed type (such as  `int`, as `char` won't be big enough either) instead.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: That is not necessarily true. `char` can have a larger range. OTOH, it can be unsigned, thus no negative values at all.

Comment: `unsigned char Image` is not even a 1D array, much less a 2D array.

Comment: @Olaf maybe, but I've never seen a system where `char` is > 8bits. Have you ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Yes I have. Have you ever programmed DSPs or custom cores e.g. in FPGAs? Or computers with 9 or 18 bit bytes?

Comment: Please provide a link to that C/C++ language. Until then there are only the two **different** languages C and C++! Pick one.

Comment: My image is also of type unsigned char. @MichaelWalz I see your point, so what happens in the result image when we perform correlation or convolution in c++. Can you explain if you have any idea.

Comment: Maybe the word "unsigned" is not clear enough. FYI: an `unsigned` integer type can only hold zero or a positive integer. Why do you expect it to hold a negative value? And youi also mix-in a float, which is alltogether a bad idea. There are some implemenatitions for integer operations; maybe you find them with some search effort. Also, signed integers are not necessarily represented as 2's complement.

Comment: I am stressing on unsigned char as the image pixels range from 0 to 255.

Comment: Maybe you better provide a [mcve].

Comment: When doing image processing you usually want perform the arithmatic with types of higher range (and precision) and then saturate the results. You might also want to look up saturating arithmetic.

Comment: @Olaf: Out of curiosity: Would the answer be different for C or C++?

Comment: @MikeMB: Can you prove it cannot?

Comment: If `res` need only hold values -128 to 127, then code  `signed char res` or `int8_t res`. If `res` need only hold values -32768 to 32767, then code  `signed short res` or `int16_t res`, etc.

Comment: @Olaf: I can't (or rather I don't have the relevant standard documents at hand right now - and even if I had I'd probably mess up) thats why I'm asking. I'm genuenly interested in the answer. There are so many rules about integral promotion, implicit (narrowing) conversion and over/underflow, that I wouldn't be suprised if some details are different between C and C++ - in particular there might be some implementation defined rules involved.

Comment: MikeMB's comment about needing a higher intermediate higher range or using saturation arithmetic is the correct one.  Algorithms like these can generate values outside the final output's range so one has to determine how they want to solve that in a way appropriate to their domain.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I save the result as -149 but the type still remains as unsigned char?

Don't do it. Use a signed integral type.

Use `int` if the increased memory usage is not an issue.
Failing that, use `short`.

Comment: Memory efficiency is also my concern. May be I should change the result image type to be of `short int`.

Comment: @Tanya, I would strongly advise that.

Comment: @R Sahu Ok. But, in most of the tutorials images are represented as `unsigned char`. So I am trying to code that way.

Comment: @Tanya, that makes sense. Perhaps there is something missing from your logic in the computation. When would the value of an element of an image matrix be negative? What does that correspond to in an image?

Comment: @ R Sahu When would the value of an element of an image matrix be negative? When is explained in my question itself. The result of correlation. What does that correspond to in an image? That correspond to image pixels/intensity values, which I'm trying to save in an `unsigned char`. I think if I want to save as `unsigned char`, I should round the negative values to zero. I'm not sure if that is what done in standard coding, and so I asked this question.

Comment: @Tanya, in the physical world, a pixel intensity cannot be negative. Hence, my question about your computation logic. If the computation can be negative, what does it represent in the real world?

Answer (score 1):

When computing a gradient [-X 0 X] on an image of range [0 max], your results is into the range [-X*max, X*max]. There are different ways to handle it according to your needs and constraints:

1. If you don't have memory concerns, you increase the encoding (byte -> short, short -> int).
2. If you are interested but gradient intensity and not its sign, you first apply an absolute value in order to get the new resulting range [0, X*max], and you go apply the third solution
3. You stretch your result in order to fit into the range you desire, meaning you apply an histogram stretching (linear function): [-X*max, X*max] -> [0 max]. Unfortunately this solution looses a lot of precision. With you example, this solution looses half of the precision (from [-255, 255)] to [0, 255]), except if you apply the point 2 before.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, when I perform correlation, the result from first row is -149 mathematically, but the printed result is 107 (2's complement).  Isn't that a mistake?

```
unsigned char res = -1.F *(Kernel[i-1]) + (Kernel[i+1]);
```

Saving a negative value in a unsigned variable, like `res`, does not change the type of `res`.  It is forever `unsigned char`.  The negative value is converted by repeatedly adding/(or subtracting) `UCHAR_MAX + 1` (256) and until it is in the range of `unsigned char` or in this case: `107`.

To save a negative value and have the negative value retained in `res`, use a signed type that meets the range requirements:

```
Type          Range of Type 
signed char   at least [-127 to 127]      Varies by platform
signed short  at least [-32767 to 32767]  Varies by platform
int8_t        exactly  [-128 to 127]
int16_t       exactly  [-32768 to 32767]
```